# Vue js - form resetting while hiding and unhiding

Tags: vue.js

I am making a listing website, in the listing page i have 2 parts, one is search form and the other is listing.

The search form is hidden initially, after clicking the filter icon , search form will appear,

Everything working fine,But the issue is, for example i enetered a keyword to search , then hitting the search button, then listing came.After this, i again clicked the filter icon, then the search form is cleared, i mean the keyword field is empty.How can i prevent that resetting

my search form components is like

```html
<div v-if="content_filter">
  <Filters 
    :identity="identity" 
    :main_category="main_category_id" 
    :category="category_id"
  />
</div>
<div v-if="content_listing">
  here comes listing
</div>
```

And my search filter icon action to show and hide is like

```js
openFilter() {
  console.log(this.content_filter);
  if(this.content_filter==true) {
    this.progress=false;
    this.content=true;
    this.content_filter=false;
    this.content_listing=true;
  } else {
    this.progress=false;
    this.content=true;
    this.content_filter=true;
    this.content_listing=false;
  }
}
```

I am just hiding and showing the filter, then y it is resetting the value??

Comment: have you pass the `keyword` from the parent component to the `Filters` component? or the `keyword` is a `data` of `Filters`?

Comment: @DengSihan keyword is the data of Filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-if` unmounts children when a condition is false. If child state contains a form, it will be reset on every `v-if` condition switch.

In order to preserve filter state between `v-if` condition changes, `keyword` should be moved to a parent and be passed to `Filters` with two-way binding, e.g. `v-model`.

The alternative is to not unmount `Filters` but make it invisible. This is achieved with [`v-show` directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-show).